# how to check broadcast unregister or not in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver, ondestroy

In my activity I try to unregister the `Broadcast Receiver`. I'm simply putting this line for unregister that.

```
unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
```

But the problem is that my `Broadcast` is unregister on two condition

1) One if I get the result in my `onActvityResult`

2) `onDestroy`

But problem is that when my `Broadcast Receiver` unregister from the `onActvityResult` and when user try to close the `Activity` my `onDestroy` is called and my application is crashed.

> **My Logcat:**
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not
>   registered:
>   com.coincide.ridetog.post_ride.PostRideActvity$MyBroadcastReceiver@831c755
>                                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:782)
>                                                                             at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1205)
>                                                                             at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:586)
>                                                                             at
>   com.coincide.ridetog.post_ride.PostRideActvity.onDestroy(PostRideActvity.java:300)

**Here is my `onDestroy()`**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (myBroadcastReceiver!=null) {
        unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are already checking if myBroadcastReceiver is not null. what is stopping you from obvious(for programmer) way of using it?

Comment: Also it seems like some kind of missuse of BroadcastReceiver ... did you tried if your app works if "Do not keep activities" is on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following method in your activity and call it in your onResume and in your onActivityResult callbacks. Once method is called it will set your myBroadcastReceiver instance to null, so it will avoid to execute multiple times until you create a new myBroadcastReceiver instance.

```
private void unregisterMyBroadcastReceiver() {
    if (null != myBroadcastReceiver) {
        unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
        myBroadcastReceiver = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is so ovbious ... :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexTa thats work for me. The mistake i am doing that i am thinking that when i unregister the broadcast it become null. but your answer is the correct way to do that. thanks alot people like you make this Stackoverflow very helpfull